# Не работает framewor kivy из-за OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

[image: что делать чтобы не было kivy fatal error]

Ошибка:

> OpenGL version detected: 1.1
>   Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems.

Comment: возможно поможет эта ветка на англоязычной SO, как я понимаю зависит в том числе от версии ОС https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969990/kivy-does-not-detect-opengl-2-0

Comment: Не следует задавать один и тот же вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обновите драйвер видеокарты и/или OpenGl. Там же написано в ошибке

OpenGl должен быть не ниже 2.0, так же указанно в ошибке

Comment: не у меня все обновлено но ваше другое собшение с веткой angl  SO помогло огромное огромное спасибо

Comment: Вот и хорошо!!!

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я могу судить, это [старая проблема](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3576).

Там, где работаете с kivy, добавьте:

```
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
```

Ещё может помочь такой вариант:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
```

Comment: не помогло․․․․․․․․․