# Не работает framework kivy из-за OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

[image: k]

Выдает ошибку из-за opengl
я скачал opengl version 4.4 но не помогло что делать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает framewor kivy из-за OpenGL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066462/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-framewor-kivy-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0-opengl)